# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 java exception

Tags: java, android

This exception occurs while running a fragment trying to display a ListView of objects. I have researched the exception but the solution for other cases seems to have to do with the "setText" function, or anything else trying to display anything else than a string as a string. I'm really not sure what else to say. Thanks in advance!

Java Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import in.galaxyofandroid.spinerdialog.OnSpinerItemClick;
import in.galaxyofandroid.spinerdialog.SpinnerDialog;

import static android.R.attr.name;
import static android.R.attr.value;
import static com.company.ingredismartv2.R.id.add;
import static com.company.ingredismartv2.R.id.fragment;
import static com.company.ingredismartv2.R.id.nav_kitchen;

public class Kitchen extends Fragment {

public Kitchen() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
Button add;
ArrayList<String> listOfIngs = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kitchen, container, false);
    add = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
        }
    });

    IngAdapter adapter = new IngAdapter(getContext(), listOfIngs);
    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return root;

}

public class IngAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IngAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> ings) {
        super(context, 0, ings);
    }


}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    spinnerDialog = new SpinnerDialog(getActivity(), ingredients, "Select An Ingredient");

    final Ing tomatoSauce = new Ing("Tomato Sauce", 0 ,0);
    listOfIngs.add(tomatoSauce.name);
    final Ing chicken = new Ing("Chicken", 0 ,0);
    listOfIngs.add(chicken.name);
    final Ing olives = new Ing("Olives", 0, 0);
    listOfIngs.add(olives.name);

    ingredients.add("Tomato Sauce");
    ingredients.add("Chicken");
    ingredients.add("Olives");

    ArrayList<Ing> ing = new ArrayList<>();



    spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(String Ingredient, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(Kitchen.super.getContext(), "Selected "+Ingredient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(Ingredient.equals(tomatoSauce.name)) {

                if (tomatoSauce.init == 0){

                    tomatoSauce.init = 1;

                }

            } else if(Ingredient.equals(chicken.name)) {

                if (chicken.init == 0){

                    chicken.init = 1;

                }

            } else if(Ingredient.equals(olives.name)){

                if (olives.init == 0){

                    olives.init = 1;

                }

            }

        }
    });


}

ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();



public class Ing {

    int init;

    int value;

    String name;

    Ing(String name, int value, int init) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.init = init;
    }


}
```

}

XML Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.company.ingredismartv2.Kitchen">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:text="Add An Ingredient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list">

        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Edit (logs)

```
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
          Build Date: 04/06/15 Mon
          Local Branch: 
          Remote Branch: 
          Local Patches: 
          Reconstruct Branch: 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
`enter code here`W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.comapany.ingredismartv2, PID: 9504
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2652)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1082)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                  at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.FrameLay
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9504 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: post your  logcat

Comment: This has majorly to do with your findviewbyid not able to find the correct resource with that ID. Post your logs and also check for resource names and clean build it again

Comment: logs have been posted

Comment: @Keith Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your error. Its in your line  below in your IngAdapter

```
super(context, 0, ings);
```

In this the 2nd parameter should be the resource name and should never be hardcoded by any int value. This is the identifier of the layout which will be used for creating each row in your list. If you just want to display the list of names you can use - **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** which is a standard available in android for displaying just String values.

So change your code to

```
super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ings);
```